# Adding widths of all list elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a menu item as below:

```
<ul id="ulMyMenu">                
     <li >testitem</li>
     <li >TestTestItem</li>
    <li >TestTestItemItem Item</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the width of all `<li/>` inside the `<ul/>` added together.
I wrote a script for this:

```
var len=0;
$("#ulMyMenu").children("li").each(function(index,element){
len=len+ $(element).css("width");
});
console.log(len);
```

But the result is like all the lengths are taken as string and added together.Something like this is I'm getting `036px47px46px`. Is it possible to add the magnitudes instead adding it as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the `width` to a `number` by using `.parseInt()` before involving that into a calculation,

```
$("#ulMyMenu").children("li").each(function(index,element){
  len += parseInt($(element).css("width"),10);
});
```

FYKI: `.css('width')` would always return values as a string.

You may ask *why should i use `.parseInt()` specifically.? can't i use `+`/`Number()` to convert that.?*

The answer is *12px would be `NAN` if you convert it by using the methods other than `parseInt()`*

Comment: @Arvin Its a radix, that decides the method for conversion.

Comment: it is optional but advised to use radix in paresint

Answer (score 1):

Try using `paresInt()` as shown:

```
len = len + parseInt( $(element).css("width"),10 );
```

Complete code :

```
$("#ulMyMenu").children("li").each(function(index,element){
  len += parseInt( $(element).css("width"),10 );
});
```

In javascript/jquery whenever you deal with numbers use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` otherwise values are treated as `string`.